# How to get the required fields data from an Entity to VO object using Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

In Spring Data Jpa we have a flexibility to map the required fields query result to a VO object with out exposing the entity object outside.

DB Used :: mysql

### 1st way ::

```
@Query("SELECT new CountryVO(c.id,c.name) FROM Country c")
public List<CountryVO> getCountries();
```

//Country Entity

```
public class Country{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @DBRef 
    private State state;
}
```

// State Entity

```
   public class State{
       private long id;
       private String name;
   }
```

//Country VO

```
public class CountryVO{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String stateName;
}
```

### 2nd way ::

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT c.name FROM Country c")
public List<String> getNames();
```

Now my point is I am using Spring Data mongoDB with mongoDB database and here the querying way is different like below

```
@Query(value = "{}", fields = "{'id':1,'name':1,'state.name':1}")
List<CountryVO> getAllCountries();
```

In the above query we can mention what ever fields we want in the fields attribute and the remaining fields will come as null values, but I want to map the output result to a VO like Spring Data Jpa.

Please let me know any possibilities

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just use your `CountyVO` as return type:

```
@Query(value = "{}", fields = "{'id':1,'name':1}")
List<CountryVO> getAllCountries();
```

Comment: This is working fine for the first level variables, but for the referenced documents am getting null value in the query. Please look at the edited version of this question

Comment: Well, this edit changes the picture completely. MongoDB doesn't support database-level joins, so that won't work.